# What's the difference in meaning between "act a certain way" and "act in a certain way"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, american-english

What's the difference in meaning between "act a certain way" and "act in a certain way"?

It confuses me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you say

> He acted a certain way.
>   He *acted like a criminal*.

you are describing exactly how *he* acted and your description is very accurate.

If you say

> He acted **in** a certain way.
>   He acted *in a suspicious way*.
>   He acted *in a criminal way*.

you're description doesn't not nail down all the details to exactly describe how *he* acted, but you are saying he acted in a similar way to *something*, that his actions taken together makes him seem suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of both the words (***"act in a certain way" and "act a certain way"***) is same but if you use prepositions in English language it look like quite professional. Believers believe that, if we use preposition it look like a proper phrase.